# Position element relative to page

Tags: javascript, css-position

I have this element, and i want to position it to specific coordinates on the page. The problem is that **it's inside another positioned element**, so position:absolute places it relatively to this element, while i want it to be placed relatively to the page.

Is there some way i can place an element at specific coordinates on the page?

You can see what i have on this page: http://bit.ly/NkfJk7 when you mouse over that yellow exclamation icon, i want the pink box to appear near that, but instead it appears in double that distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, i was doing it wrong.

```
toolTip.style.left = button.offsetLeft + "px";
toolTip.style.top = button.offsetTop + "px";
```

No need to go absolute :)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `position: fixed` for this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position

> Fixed
>
> Do not leave space for the element.  Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page.

---

**EDIT:** Disregard this answer. Position-fixed positions relative to the screen, so it will follow around it the page scrolls.

Comment: this is not what he wants, if the user scrolls the page the overlay stays fixed while his element (the icon) is scrolling with the rest of the page.